# React context returns initial state every time using it - despite setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have created this simple authentication component.
When app is refreshed and `ContextProvider` is loaded `useEffect` method is fired and sets user logged in.

***Have a look at code***

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import User from 'utils/User/User';
import useLocale from 'store/LocaleContext';
import { tokenKey } from 'consts';

const AuthContext = createContext();

const initialState = { auth: false, user: null };

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const { setLanguage } = useLocale();

  const loginUser = user => {
    setLanguage(user.getLanguage());
    user.login();
    setState({ ...state, user: user, auth: true });

    setTimeout(() => {
      logOutUser();
    }, 2000);
  };

  const logOutUser = () => {
    console.log(state.user, state); // Output: null, {auth: false, user: null}
    state.user.logout();
    setState(initialState);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    User.Credentials.loginWithToken(localStorage.getItem(tokenKey))
      .then(data => data.data)
      .then(data => {
        if (data.success && data.user) {
          loginUser(new User(data.user));
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        logOutUser();
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        auth: state.auth,
        user: state.user,
        loginUser,
        logout: logOutUser
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

`loginUser` method executes correctly but then I want to test `logoutUser` function.
So I decided to run `logoutUser` function after 2 second of logging in, but it reads old state.

When I log `state` and `state.user` I get output:  `null, {auth: false, user: null}`. So as you can see it reads `initialState` or state is not changing.

Can you tell me what's problem and what I'm doing wrong?

Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.  Both related to useState being asynchronous.

1. You need to use a function as the first parameter passed to setState.  React will call it with the at-call-time-current state and expect you to return an Object to merge into state.

`setState(state => ([...state, user: user, auth: true]));`

2. You need to use the Hook `useEffect()` to make sure you are getting the updated version of state when you `console.log()`.

`useEffect(() => { console.log(state) }, [state]);`

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I tried firs one but got same result. Note: When I call logout function from header component ( or somewhere else) it works correctly and logs user details. But whenI call it from context it returns `initialState`

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze : did you ever find a solution ?